# Sum a list of numbers in Python

Tags: python, list, sum

Given a list of numbers such as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
```

How do I calculate their total sum:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ...
```

How do I calculate their pairwise averages:

```
[(1+2)/2, (2+3)/2, (3+4)/2, (4+5)/2, ...]
```

Answer (score 368):

###### Question 1:

To sum a list of numbers, use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sum(xs))
```

This outputs:

```
15
```

---

###### Question 2:

So you want (element 0 + element 1) / 2, (element 1 + element 2) / 2, ... etc.

We make two lists: one of every element except the first, and one of every element except the last. Then the averages we want are the averages of each pair taken from the two lists. We use `zip` to take pairs from two lists.

I assume you want to see decimals in the result, even though your input values are integers. By default, Python does integer division: it discards the remainder. To divide things through all the way, we need to use floating-point numbers. Fortunately, dividing an int by a float will produce a float, so we just use `2.0` for our divisor instead of `2`.

Thus:

```
averages = [(x + y) / 2.0 for (x, y) in zip(my_list[:-1], my_list[1:])]
```

Comment: Since `zip` stops once it reaches the end of the shorter argument, `zip(my_list, my_list[1:])` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, and that's how I usually see it written; stylistically I prefer the symmetry of slicing both, although it's less efficient.

Comment: I swapped the order of the [sub-questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) to make this more useful for the most common case that most beginners are searching for. Also, the question/top answer have 2 million views but very few upvotes in comparison to other popular questions (that have 10x the upvotes!). Perhaps this is an indication that the less common "sub-question" should be removed altogether. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq please take this issue to [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). My first reaction is that I agree, but this needs to be discussed.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq even a very low scoring, unpopular question is better to use as the canonical if it meets standards while this one does not (it is clearly two completely unrelated questions, and thus "needs more focus"). The best I've found specifically for the `sum` question so far (i.e., without introducing any other weird requirements such as converting strings to integers - i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344827/summing-elements-in-a-list is **not** good enough) is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472771/how-to-sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python; but I will keep looking.

Comment: Despite how it was initially received, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909052/how-do-i-add-together-integers-in-a-list-in-python might be better.

Comment: We might also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344827 , which could be edited to remove the incidental questions about preparing the input.

Answer (score 145):

To sum a list of numbers:

```
sum(list_of_nums)
```

---

Generate a new list with adjacent elements averaged in `xs` using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[(x + y) / 2 for x, y in zip(xs, xs[1:])]
```

Sum all those adjacent elements into a single value:

```
sum((x + y) / 2 for x, y in zip(xs, xs[1:]))
```

Comment: I think he wants to sum adjacent elements. There would be no point in taking the average of `x` and `x - 1`; we could just subtract 0.5 instead.

Comment: The reduce function does not do what the post says.
It calculates (((a1+a2)/2 + a3)/2 + a4)/2 ...

Comment: `from functools import reduce`

Answer (score 79):

**Question 2:**
To sum a list of integers:

```
a = [2, 3, 5, 8]
sum(a)
# 18
# or you can do:
sum(i for i in a)
# 18
```

If the list contains integers as strings:

```
a = ['5', '6']
# import Decimal: from decimal import Decimal
sum(Decimal(i) for i in a)
```

Comment: `sum(i for i in a)` is just redundant.

Comment: `sum(Decimal(i) for i in a)` => `sum(int(i) for i in a)` or `sum(map(int,a))`

Answer (score 35):

You can try this way:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
sm = sum(a[0:len(a)]) # Sum of 'a' from 0 index to 9 index. sum(a) == sum(a[0:len(a)]
print(sm) # Python 3
print sm  # Python 2
```

Comment: no need to create a copy like this, and it's horribly unpythonic. Avoid like the plague despite all the votes...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre could you please details your comment ? Why is this "horribly unpythonic" ?

Comment: for starters `a[0:len(a)]` creates a copy of `a`, what's the point besides wasting CPU & memory? then `print(sm)` also works in python 2. I don't understand why this has so many upvotes in mid-2017... but it applies to most of the answers here.

Answer (score 28):

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> sum(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> del sum
>>> sum(a)
45
```

It seems that `sum` has been defined in the code somewhere and overwrites the default function. So I deleted it and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 17):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344827/summing-elements-in-a-list)

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
sum(a)
```

sum(a) returns 10

Comment: How does this add anything to answers that existed as early as 2010?

Answer (score 16):

Using a simple `list-comprehension` and the `sum`:

```
>> sum(i for i in range(x))/2. #if x = 10 the result will be 22.5
```

Comment: You don't need to use `[` and `]`, you can just pass the generator expression `sum(i/2. for i in range(x))`

Comment: `sum(range(x)) / 2.` avoids all the divisions, just divide in the end.

Answer (score 14):

All answers did show a programmatic and general approach. I suggest a mathematical approach specific for your case. It can be faster in particular for long lists. It works because your list is a list of natural numbers up to `n`:

Let's assume we have the natural numbers `1, 2, 3, ..., 10`:

```
>>> nat_seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You can use the `sum` function on a list:

```
>>> print sum(nat_seq)
55
```

You can also use the formula `n*(n+1)/2` where `n` is the value of the last element in the list (here: `nat_seq[-1]`), so you avoid iterating over elements:

```
>>> print (nat_seq[-1]*(nat_seq[-1]+1))/2
55
```

To generate the sequence `(1+2)/2, (2+3)/2, ..., (9+10)/2` you can use a generator and the formula `(2*k-1)/2.` (note the dot to make the values floating points). You have to skip the first element when generating the new list:

```
>>> new_seq = [(2*k-1)/2. for k in nat_seq[1:]]
>>> print new_seq
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]
```

Here too, you can use the `sum` function on that list:

```
>>> print sum(new_seq)
49.5
```

But you can also use the formula `(((n*2+1)/2)**2-1)/2`, so you can avoid iterating over elements:

```
>>> print (((new_seq[-1]*2+1)/2)**2-1)/2
49.5
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to solve this problem:

```
l =[1,2,3,4,5]
sum=0
for element in l:
    sum+=element
print sum
```

Comment: How is this simpler than `sum(l)`?

Comment: Indeed sum(l) is a calling function. A library should understand what is meant by sum function

Answer (score 6):

So many solutions, but my favourite is still missing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

a numpy array is not too different from a list (in this use case), except that you can treat arrays like numbers:

```
>>> ( arr[:-1] + arr[1:] ) / 2.0
[ 1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5]
```

Done!

**explanation**

The fancy indices mean this: `[1:]` includes all elements from 1 to the end (thus omitting element 0), and `[:-1]` are all elements except the last one:

```
>>> arr[:-1]
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> arr[1:]
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

So adding those two gives you an array consisting of elements (1+2), (2+3) and so on.
Note that I'm dividing by `2.0`, not `2` because otherwise Python believes that you're only using integers and produces rounded integer results.

**advantage of using numpy**

Numpy can be **much** faster than loops around lists of numbers. Depending on how big your list is, several orders of magnitude faster. Also, it's a lot less code, and at least to me, it's easier to read.
I'm trying to make a habit out of using numpy for all groups of numbers, and it is a huge improvement to all the loops and loops-within-loops I would otherwise have had to write.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `pairwise` [itertools recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
import itertools
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

def pair_averages(seq):
    return ( (a+b)/2 for a, b in pairwise(seq) )
```

Comment: As of Python 3.10, this is now [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise): `from itertools import pairwise` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Generators are an easy way to write this:

```
from __future__ import division
# ^- so that 3/2 is 1.5 not 1

def averages( lst ):
    it = iter(lst) # Get a iterator over the list
    first = next(it)
    for item in it:
        yield (first+item)/2
        first = item

print list(averages(range(1,11)))
# [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]
```

Comment: You can also divide by 2.0 to avoid integer division.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson not true in python 3. floating point division is the default.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np    
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
[(np.mean((x[i],x[i+1]))) for i in range(len(x)-1)]
# [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us make it easy for Beginner:-

1. The `global` keyword will allow the global variable message to be assigned within the main function without producing a new local variable

> ```
>     message = "This is a global!"
>
>
> def main():
>     global message
>     message = "This is a local"
>     print(message)
>
>
> main()
> # outputs "This is a local" - From the Function call
> print(message)
> # outputs "This is a local" - From the Outer scope
> ```

This concept is called **Shadowing**

2. Sum a list of numbers in Python

> ```
> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>
> var = 0
>
>
> def sums():
>     for num in nums:
>         global var
>         var = var + num
>     print(var)
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     sums()
> ```

Outputs = **15**

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.8, the new assignment operator can be used

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> itr = iter(my_list)
>>> a = next(itr)
>>> [(a + (a:=x))/2 for x in itr]
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
```

`a` is a running reference to the *previous* value in the list, hence it is initialized to the first element of the list and the iteration occurs over the *rest* of the list, updating `a` after it is used in each iteration.

An explicit iterator is used to avoid needing to create a copy of the list using `my_list[1:]`.

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple:

```
def ave(x,y):
  return (x + y) / 2.0

map(ave, a[:-1], a[1:])
```

And here's how it looks:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> map(ave, a[:-1], a[1:])
[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5]
```

Due to some stupidity in how Python handles a `map` over two lists, you do have to truncate the list, `a[:-1]`. It works more as you'd expect if you use `itertools.imap`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.imap(ave, a, a[1:])
<itertools.imap object at 0x1005c3990>
>>> list(_)
[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5]
```

Comment: Short, yes. Simple? It requires an explanation longer than the long solutions to understand what it's doing.

Comment: this introduces floating point accumulation error. Divide in the end instead.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Both methods are imperfect - dividing at the end will overflow for large numbers, the solution depends on the data (and the use case).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the same using recursion:

**Python Snippet:**

```
def sumOfArray(arr, startIndex):
    size = len(arr)
    if size == startIndex:  # To Check empty list
        return 0
    elif startIndex == (size - 1): # To Check Last Value
        return arr[startIndex]
    else:
        return arr[startIndex] + sumOfArray(arr, startIndex + 1)


print(sumOfArray([1,2,3,4,5], 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of itertools. Inspiration from the pairwise recipe.

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def average(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1)/2.0, (s1,s2)/2.0, ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return ((x+y)/2.0 for x, y in izip(a, b))
```

Examples:

```
>>>list(average([1,2,3,4,5]))
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5]
>>>list(average([1,20,31,45,56,0,0]))
[10.5, 25.5, 38.0, 50.5, 28.0, 0.0]
>>>list(average(average([1,2,3,4,5])))
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a `while` loop to get the result:

```
i = 0
while i < len(a)-1:
   result = (a[i]+a[i+1])/2
   print result
   i +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through elements in the list and update the total like this:

```
def sum(a):
    total = 0
    index = 0
    while index < len(a):
        total = total + a[index]
        index = index + 1
    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to *Karl Knechtel* i was able to understand your question. My interpretation:

1. You want a new list with the average of the element i and i+1.
2. You want to sum each element in the list.

**First** question using anonymous function (aka. Lambda function):

```
s = lambda l: [(l[0]+l[1])/2.] + s(l[1:]) if len(l)>1 else []  #assuming you want result as float
s = lambda l: [(l[0]+l[1])//2] + s(l[1:]) if len(l)>1 else []  #assuming you want floor result
```

**Second** question also using anonymous function (aka. Lambda function):

```
p = lambda l: l[0] + p(l[1:]) if l!=[] else 0
```

**Both** questions combined in a single line of code :

```
s = lambda l: (l[0]+l[1])/2. + s(l[1:]) if len(l)>1 else 0  #assuming you want result as float
s = lambda l: (l[0]+l[1])/2. + s(l[1:]) if len(l)>1 else 0  #assuming you want floor result
```

*use the one that fits best your needs*

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list comprehension. Something like:

```
new_list = [(old_list[i] + old_list[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(old_list-1))]
```

Comment: @Rafe it's a *working* one (if we just fix the parentheses at the end - should be `range(len(old_list) - 1)`), but Pythonistas generally frown upon the combination of 'range' and 'len'. A corollary to "there should only be one way to do it" is "the standard library provides a way for you to avoid ugly things". Indirect iteration - iterating over a sequence of numbers, so that you can use those numbers to index what you really want to iterate over - is an ugly thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a lambda with map()

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = map(lambda x, y: (x+y)/2.0, fib[:-1], fib[1:])
print b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of array: "))
list1 = []
for i in range(n):
    list1.append(int(input("Enter numbers: ")))
print("User inputs are", list1)

list2 = []
for j in range(0, n-1):
    list2.append((list1[j]+list1[j+1])/2)
print("result = ", list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use the iter_tools permutation

```
# If you are given a list

numList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

# and you are asked to find the number of three sums that add to a particular number

target = 10
# How you could come up with the answer?

from itertools import permutations

good_permutations = []

for p in permutations(numList, 3):
    if sum(p) == target:
        good_permutations.append(p)

print(good_permutations)
```

The result is:

```
[(1, 2, 7), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 5, 4), (1, 6, 3), (1, 7, 2), (2, 1, 7), (2, 3, 
5), (2, 5, 3), (2, 7, 1), (3, 1, 6), (3, 2, 5), (3, 5, 2), (3, 6, 1), (4, 1, 5), (4, 
5, 1), (5, 1, 4), (5, 2, 3), (5, 3, 2), (5, 4, 1), (6, 1, 3), (6, 3, 1), (7, 1, 2), 
(7, 2, 1)]
```

Note that order matters - meaning 1, 2, 7 is also shown as 2, 1, 7 and 7, 1, 2.  You can reduce this by using a set.

Comment: This answer seems to be unrelated to the question. The question has nothing to do with triples of numbers which sum to a given target.

Answer (score -4):

Try the following -

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]   

def add(mylist):
    total = 0
    for i in mylist:
        total += i
    return total

result = add(mylist)
print("sum = ", result)
```

Comment: A new answer should really be distinctively different from the existing answers. Also, your `sum` function does not differ from the built-in `sum` in behavior or name. You could actually delete the function definition from your answer and it would still work.

Comment: can you please check now

Comment: I appreciate that you're improving your answer! The variable names are more descriptive and don't shadow the built-ins. But the fundamental problems are still there: the for-loop approach was already provided by http://stackoverflow.com/a/35359188/733092 above, and the function is redundant with the built-in `sum`. You'd get an A on a test for answering the question correctly, but StackOverflow answers also need to be *useful* to people arriving at this page, and duplicate answers aren't.