# Summing elements in a list

Tags: python, list, sum

Here is my code, I need to sum an undefined number of elements in the list. How to do this?

```
l = raw_input()
l = l.split(' ')
l.pop(0)
```

My input: `3 5 4 9`
After input I delete first element via `l.pop(0)`.
After `.split(' ')` my list is `['5', '4', '9']` and I need to sum all elements in this list.

In this case the sum is 18. Please notice that number of elements is not defined.

Comment: @JakobBowyer I need to delete first entry

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary isn't that obvious? is a string... he used raw_input()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can sum numbers in a list simply with the [sum()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) built-in:

```
sum(your_list)
```

It will sum as many number items as you have. Example:

```
my_list = range(10, 17)
my_list
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

sum(my_list)
91
```

**For your specific case**:

For your data convert the numbers into `int` first and then sum the numbers:

```
data = ['5', '4', '9']

sum(int(i) for i in data)
18
```

This will work for **undefined** number of elements in your list (as long as they are "numbers")

Thanks for @senderle's comment re conversion in case the data is in string format.

Comment: Thanks for the solution including transformation to integers, For me it only works when I put brackets [ ] around int(i) for i in data. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. Levon forgot the brackets.

Answer (score 10):

Python iterable can be summed like so - [`[sum(range(10)[1:])]`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) . This sums all elements from the list except the first element.

```
>>> atuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
>>> sum(atuple)
15
>>> alist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> sum(alist)
15
```

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> l = raw_input()
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>>> l = l.split()
>>> l.pop(0)
'1'
>>> sum(map(int, l)) #or simply sum(int(x) for x in l) , you've to convert the elements to integer first, before applying sum()
54
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use reduce method:

```
>>> myList = [3, 5, 4, 9]
>>> myTotal = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, myList)
>>> myTotal
21
```

Furthermore, you can modify the lambda function to do other operations on your list.

Comment: The `reduce` function removed on python3 to base-module called `functools`.
src: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` to sum the elements of a list, however if your list is coming from `raw_input`, you probably want to convert the items to `int` or `float` first:

```
l = raw_input().split(' ')
sum(map(int, l))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function and pythons inbuilt `sum()` function. It simplifies the solution. And reduces the complexity.
    `a=map(int,raw_input().split())`
    `sum(a)`
Done!

Answer (score 0):

```
def sumoflist(l):    
    total = 0    
    for i in l:
        total +=i
    return total
```