# Summing elements in a list of "list", each with different index

Tags: python, list, pandas, indexing, calculation

From a loop I have a variable A:

```
aa = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
aaaa = []
aaaa.append(aa.loc[[1]])
aaaa.append(aa.loc[[4]])
aaaa

[1    0.07856
 dtype: float64, 4    0.94552
 dtype: float64]
```

Now I would like to sum up (or do any other calculation) the elements within A. I tried with the sum-function, but unfortunately it does not work. For instance,

```
B = sum(aaaa)
```

gives me

```
1   NaN
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

I have found below question and solutions, however, it does not work for my problem as the TO has only one list, and not several lists appended to each other (with different indexing)

[Summing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344827/summing-elements-in-a-list)

edit4: As I have to run this multiple times, I timed both answers:

```
%timeit sum([i.values for i in aaaa])
3.78 µs ± 5.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit pd.concat(aaaa).sum()
560 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

surprisingly the "loop" inside the sum is much faster than the pd.Series.concat().sum() function

edit5: to add in case someone else has the same problem: in case if it's not know whether the input is a pd.Series or a list of pd.Series, one could do following:

```
res = sum(aa) if isinstance(aa, pd.Series) else sum([i.values for i in aa])
```

Comment: hi jpp, apologies for that. there must be something incorrect, otherwise it would work right? I deleted the 'sum', and included how it can look like. maybe that's clearer in terms of desired result. In fact, I would have loved to show a sample, how I could produce 'A' but that's a product of part of my code.

Comment: Could you advice in this particular example? I stated what I have as an input and what I would like to do with or what result I'd like to have and a current proposed method which does not work (see adjustment above)

Comment: "... which seems to be a numpy array" look at the source code and figure out what you're dealing with before asking a question. If you don't know the data type of your "mystery" variable, and don't include the code that generates it, then how is anyone else supposed to know? The entire point of a [MCVE] is that it presents an isolated, easily testable problem. If you don't have that, then the question *probably* isn't ready to be asked.

Comment: My best guess at first glance is that you have a list of mixed data types, of which only some are supported by `sum(arg)`. I'm not entirely clear what your input or expected output is though.

Comment: actually, I hoped you guys would know. but never mind, I figured out how to reproduce the input variable. Just to stress, appending is done in this example randomly, in the original code, it's a condition to be. I think now the problem can be tested.

Comment: Just for future reference, if you run into intermittent problems when using a randomized code path, part of putting together an MCVE is selecting a specific (fixed, ie not random) example that triggers the problem, and writing a stand alone code snippet with only that. Then people can help you with the actual issue at hand.

Comment: As to this question, I'm not familiar with Pandas so you'll have to wait for someone who is to see this. It looks like your issue has to do with the data types used by Pandas `Series` not being compatible with the built-in `sum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get out of your prediciment and only you will know the one that is best for you.

When you do `aa.loc[[1]]` you end up with a pd.Series, if you do `aa.loc[1]` you will get a scalar, as well with `.iloc`.

So just by dropping the 2nd pair of square brackets in `aa.loc[[1]]` will make your code work.

`sum` needs an iterable with numbers to work. So if you want to keep the 2nd pair of square brackets the following line will work as well, although you will now get a numpy array instead of a float as answer.

`sum([i.values for i in aaaa])`

Comment: thanks, ahed87; the straighforward way would be as jpp suggested not to use the 'loc'; however, right now the list of pd.Series is what I get (without the need to modify the other part of the code).

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing `pd.Series.loc`, which is causing your list elements to be `pd.Series` instead of scalars.

Try using `pd.Series.iloc` for integer indexing:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))

A = []
A.append(s.iloc[1])
A.append(s.iloc[4])

res = sum(A)
```

Note you could perform this calculation directly via `pd.Series.sum`:

```
res = s.iloc[[1, 4]].sum()
```

If you have a list of `pd.Series`, you can use:

```
res = pd.concat(A).sum()
```

Comment: thanks, jpp. Would you have an idea, how I could make it work using the pd.Series instead of making the input a scalar, i.e. some way of transformation of A?

Comment: Yes, the solution `res = s.iloc[[1, 4]].sum()` uses `pd.Series` directly. You don't need to make a list and append items individually. Or, build your list `[1, 4]` and use it as an input.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. I do get A as a list of pd.Series from another part of my program; so, I cannot directly access 's'; so the only number I have at the end (without having to modify the other part of the code) is my 'aaaa' the list of pd.Series

Comment: thank you, yes, that delivers also the result like ahed87' suggestion.