# In python individual multiplication of list values with a loop?

Tags: python

If I have a list `data_x = [1,2,3,4]`, how do I multiply each element of `data_x` with each element of another list `data_y = [2,3,4,5]` and sum the values?

The answer should be `1*2 +2*3 +3*4+ 4*5 = 40`. I am looking for some kind of `for` loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344827/summing-elements-in-a-list

Comment: Your example contradicts your question... (you say you want to multiply each element of `data_x` with each element of `data_y`, yet you only multiply pairs of elements with the same indices)

Comment: if you want to go fully functional then you could zip them and map with * (multiplication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (using a for loop, as requested by the OP):

```
answer = 0
for i in range(len(data_x)):
    answer += (data_x[i] * data_y[i])
```

Another (quicker) way (using `list` comprehensions):

```
answer = sum([x*y for x in zip(data_x, data_y)])
## Use zip to perform index-wise operations between two lists
## zip returns a list of tuples, with each tuple at index i containing the elements of data_x[i] and data_y[i]
```

You could also try this (if you have `numpy` installed):

```
np.multiply(data_x, data_y).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to perform index wise operations between two lists:

```
sum([x * y for x, y in zip(data_x, data_y)])
```

Or a `numpy` solution using [`numpy.multiply`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) and [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
np.multiply(data_x, data_y).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to do this.

```
data_x  = [1, 2, 3, 4]
data_y = [2, 3, 4, 5]

res = sum([a * b for a, b in zip(data_x, data_y )])
print(res)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
result = sum([x * y for x, y in zip(data_x, data_y)])
```

`result = zip(data_x, data_y)` creates a zip object of tuples where each tuple `result[i]` corresponds to the values `data_x[i]` and `data_y[i]`

That is if

```
data_x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
data_y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then,

```
result = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```