# How do you add all of the elements in a list together?

Tags: python, list, math, addition

If we have a list like this `list=[1,2,3]` and want to add all of the elements up like this `1+2+3` and get the result. How do we do that?

Comment: `print(sum(your_list))` should do.

Comment: Do not use `list`. Rename it to, say `lst`, and try `sum(lst)`.

Comment: Duplicate: [Summing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344827/summing-elements-in-a-list)

Comment: There is the builtin function `sum` which you can call directly on a list to get its sum. Or if you want to go back to basics and do things yourself for learning purposes, you can write a `for`-loop. However, never name your lists `list`. This is already the name of the class `list` which handles all lists, and shadowing that name can have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest code:

```py
lst = [1,2,3]
print(sum(lst))
```