# Add number to a total in a for loop

Tags: python

I need to compute the mass of a series of objects in a list

```
for element in list:
    weight = "a calculation here"
```

How do I save the weight calculation and add it up for each time it goes through the for loop?

Comment: Don't call your list `list`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344827/summing-elements-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

```py
for element in list:
    weight += "a calculation here"
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: You forgot to initialize `weight` to 0

Comment: He doesn't have a problem with the weight variable. He might already declare it. His problem is how to accumulate weight. So I only show him the solution to the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining what the `+=` operator is doing.