# How to emulate sum() using a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

Is it possible to emulate something like sum() using [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python) ?

For example - I need to calculate the product of all elements in a list :

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
product = [magic_here for i in list]

#product is expected to be 6
```

Code that is doing the same :

```
def product_of(input):
   result = 1
   for i in input:
      result *= i
   return result
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104782/returning-the-product-of-a-list

Comment: The OP was looking for a combination of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70558247/2987828  and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54697535/2987828 : `prod(i for i in list)`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No; a list comprehension produces a list that is just as long as its input. You will need one of Python's other functional tools (specifically `reduce()` in this case) to [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) the sequence into a single value.

Comment: in Python 3 it is the [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) module

Answer (score 53):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> reduce(mul, nums)
6
```

**Python 3 Hack**

In regards to approaches such as `[total := total + x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`

This is a terrible idea. The general idea of  emulate `sum()` using a list comprehension goes against the whole purpose of a list comprehension. You should not use a list comprehension in this case.

[**Python 2.5 / 2.6 Hack**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638478/recursive-list-comprehension-in-python)

In Python `2.5` / `2.6` You could use `vars()['_[1]']` to refer to the list comprehension currently under construction. This is **horrible** and should **never** be used but it's the closest thing to what you mentioned in the question (*using a list comp to emulate a product*).

```
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [n * (vars()['_[1]'] or [1])[-1] for n in nums][-1]
6
```

Comment: egads, that's just...I don't event know.

Comment: thats actually kinda neat ... I had no idea you could do that (And no Idea when or why you would ever want to) ... but cool all the same

Comment: +1 for your even sneakier approach to getting a result thank mine ;-)

Answer (score 46):

Starting in `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can use and increment a variable within a list comprehension and thus reduce a list to the sum of its elements:

```
total = 0
[total := total + x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
# total = 15
```

This:

- Initialises a variable `total` to `0`
- For each item, `total` is incremented by the current looped item (`total := total + x`) via an **assignment expression**

Comment: [total := total + x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]][-1] would give the sum (15). You'd need the last element of your result.

Answer (score 16):

List comprehension always creates another list, so it's not useful in combining them (e.g. to give a single number). Also, there's no way to make an assignment in list comprehension, unless you're super sneaky.

The only time I'd ever see using list comprehensions as being useful for a sum method is if you only want to include specific values in the list, or you don't have a list of numbers:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
product = [i for i in list if i % 2 ==0] # only sum even numbers in the list
print sum(product)
```

or another example":

```
# list of the cost of fruits in pence
list = [("apple", 55), ("orange", 60), ("pineapple", 140), ("lemon", 80)]
product = [price for fruit, price in list]
print sum(product)
```

---

Super sneaky way to make an assignment in a list comprehension

```
dict = {"val":0}
list = [1, 2, 3]
product = [dict.update({"val" : dict["val"]*i}) for i in list]
print dict["val"] # it'll give you 6!
```

...but that's horrible :)

Answer (score 9):

Something like this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, a)
6
```

Comment: I think you meant x+y not x*y... although both give the same result for your test data

Answer (score 6):

I complement the answer of Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams with some code that uses the `reduce` operator of Python.

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 5, 10, 100]
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list_of_numbers)
```

which can also be written as

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 5, 10, 100]

def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

reduce(sum, list_of_numbers)
```

Bonus: Python provides this functionality in the built-in `sum` function. This is the most readable expression imo.

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 5, 10, 100]
sum(list_of_numbers)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> reduce(int.__mul__,[1,2,3])
6

C:\Users\Henry>python -m timeit -s "" "reduce(int.__mul__,range(10000))" 
1000 loops, best of 3: 910 usec per loop

C:\Users\Henry>python -m timeit -s "from operator import mul" "reduce(mul,range(10000))"
1000 loops, best of 3: 399 usec per loop

C:\Users\Henry>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve by using lambda with list comprehension
Since we can't assign a value in list comprehension we go with lambda

Solution:

```
>>> (lambda number_list, sum=0:[sum for number in number_list for sum in [sum + number]][-1])([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late for this discussion, but I would like to mention that list comprehentions are turing complete, and thus this can be done with a list comprehention!

This however is messy, so I have used the following trick, which makes a cummulative array, and returns the last element

```
def sum(l):
    return [c[-1] for c in [[0]] for e in l if c.append(c[-1] + e) is None][-1]
```

Answer (score -2):

Found the magic on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/436482/.

```
>>> L=[2, 3, 4]
>>> [j for j in [1] for i in L for j in [j*i]][-1]
24
```

It should be the logic like the following code.

```
L=[2, 3, 4]
P=[]
for j in [1]:
    for i in L:
        for j in [j*i]:
            P.append(j)
print(P[-1])
```

Comment: This was flagged as VLQ. Constructs an entire list, then takes just one value - so vastly inefficient and not technically "emulate with list comprehension" (which is impossible for the reasons stated in top answers). This could do as an "anti-example" but it's so bad I'm inclined to recommend deletion.

Comment: Just no... but the answer wasn't even right for doing sum. Out of morbid curiosity, I was able to make it work with this:

`[j for j in [0] for i in L for j in [j+i]][-1]`,

But in no way would I recommend this approach.

To do sum, you need to have a starting list with an identity of [0], starting with [1] works for product because you are multiplying the first number by 1, hence the change to [0]. As @ivan_pozdeev points out, this is building a new list with the operation applied to each element of the list, and then just taking the final value. This is not the same as the question.

Comment: It was my old post and `eval('*'.join(map(str,list)))` is the way I usually use..