# python : can reduce be translated into list comprehensions like map, lambda and filter?

Tags: python, list, reduce, map-function

When programming in python, I now avoid `map`, `lambda` and `filter` by using list comprehensions because it is easier to read and faster in execution. But can `reduce` be replaced as well?

E.g. an object has an operator `union()` that works on another object, `a1.union(a2)`, and gives a 3rd object of same type.

I have a list of objects:

```
L = [a1, a2, a3, ...]
```

How to have the union() of all these objects with list comprehensions, the equivalent of:

```
result = reduce(lambda a, b :a.union(b), L[1:], L[0])
```

Comment: In some cases: no. But depends. Please provide a specific query that you have in mind

Comment: @sshashank124 - any examples?

Comment: Set unions are a bad example, because you can simply do `result = set().union(*L)`, which has the bonus of working even if L is an empty list. At any rate, `lambda a, b :a.union(b)` can be written more concisely as `set.union`, since in python `obj.method(args)` is the same as `cls.method(obj, args)`

Comment: Guido says to use a for loop instead of reduce. He's not a fan of FP constructs.

Answer (score 21):

It is no secret that reduce is [not among the favored functions](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) of the Pythonistas.

Generically, [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is a [left fold on a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Folds_in_various_languages)

It is conceptually easy to write a fold in Python that will fold left or right on a iterable:

```
def fold(func, iterable, initial=None, reverse=False):
    x=initial
    if reverse:
        iterable=reversed(iterable)
    for e in iterable:
        x=func(x,e) if x is not None else e
    return x
```

Without some atrocious hack, this cannot be replicated in a comprehension because there is not accumulator type function in a comprehension.

Just use reduce -- or write one that makes more sense to you.

Comment: Hi dawg, do you think this still holds true that you can't recreate reduce in a list comprehension in 2023. Great answer regardless

Comment: @Topde: Since `reduce` produces a single value and a comprehension produces a list (or set or dict) then it is still true that you have to have some syntax in addition to the comprehension. You *can* generate all the values that get reduced, but that is not really the same thing...

Comment: True thanks for responding, I guess we'll keep using reduce for a while then!

in my case I've got a function that will check if any value in the input columns is null

def is_null(*cols):
    """Returns true if there's at least one null across all columns."""
    return reduce(Column.__or__, [F.col(c).isNull() for c in cols])

the input number of columns can vary so this is a dynamic way of handling that, you can think of this as any('a','b', null)

Answer (score 8):

Since a list comprehension definitionally generates another list, you can't use it to generate a single value. The aren't *for* that. (Well... there is [this nasty trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632125/12779) that uses a leaked implementation detail in old versions of python that can do it. I'm not even going to copy the example code here. Don't do this.)

If you're worried about the stylistic aspects of `reduce()` and its ilk, don't be. Name your reductions and you'll be fine. So while:

```
all_union = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), L[1:], L[0])
```

isn't great, this:

```
from functools import reduce

def full_union(input):
    """ Compute the union of a list of sets """
    return reduce(set.union, input[1:], input[0])

result = full_union(L)
```

is pretty clear.

If you're worried about *speed,* check out the [toolz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toolz/) and [cytoolz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cytoolz/0.6.1) packages, which are 'fast' and 'insanely fast,' respectively. On large datasets, they'll often let you avoid processing your data more than once or loading the whole set in memory at once, in contrast to list comprehensions.

Comment: To make the `reduce()` expression itself readable, make the first argument not a lambda. For example: `reduce(set.union, <list of sets>)` Sometimes this will require you to define (and therefore name) the operator somewhere outside the call to `reduce`.

Answer (score 5):

A common use of reduce is to flatten a list of lists. You can use a list comprehension instead.

```
L = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

## with reduce

```
from functools import reduce  # python 3
flattened = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, L)

print(flattened)

[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

## with list comp

```
flattened = [item for sublist in L for item in sublist]

print(flattened)

[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

If your problem can be solved by operating on the flattened list, this is an effective replacement. Contrast these one-liners for the given example:

```
all_union = reduce(lambda a, b: set(a).union(set(b)), L)

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

all_union = set([item for sublist in L for item in sublist])

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: Use `sum(L, [])`. That said, the sum/list comprehension creates a "full-length" list, where `reduce(operator.or_, map(set, L), set())` would not.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/

Answer (score 4):

Not really. List comprehensions are more similar to `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most readable reduce for unions, but assignment expressions can be used to solve it in a single expression:

```
In [51]: L = [{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}]

In [52]: reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), L[1:], L[0])
Out[52]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

In [53]: (s := set(), [s := s.union(x) for x in L][-1])[1]
Out[53]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: How on earth is this more readable than reduce