# count a character(both uppercase and lowercase) in a string, using a for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, count

```
def eCount (s):

    """Count the e's in a string, using for loop.

    Params: s (string)
    Returns: (int) #e in s, either lowercase or uppercase
    """

    # INSERT YOUR CODE HERE, replacing 'pass'
```

The professor asks not to change anything above.
I'm trying to accomplish:

```
count = 0
for e in s:
    count +=1
return count
```

It gives:

```
(executing lines 1 to 17 of "e_count_103.py")

15
```

Comment: `for e in s:` does not do what you think it does. Try printing the value of `e` on each iteration. Also, you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: `return s.lower().count('e')`  or `return s.upper().count('E')` try this

Answer (score 3):

you can try `count()` like:
`return s.lower().count('e')`

In python 3:

```
def eCount(s):
    return s.lower().count('e')
s = "helloEeeeeE"
print(eCount(s))
```

Output:

```
7
```

You can either lowercase the string or uppercase it's up to you. (For upper case you can use `s.upper().count('E')`).For detail read [String count() tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm).

Or if you want to use `for` loop then try this ( in python 3):

```
def eCount(s):
    count = 0
    s = s.lower()
    for i in s:
        if i == 'e':
            count+=1
    return count
s = "helloEeeeeE"
print(eCount(s))
```

It gives same output:

```
7
```

> **Note :**  `e` you used in your code in this statement : `for e in s:` is not character `'e'` but variable `e` so it iterate number of characters in
>   the string and every time incrementing the `count` variable.

You can also use *list comprehension* :

```
def eCount(s):
    return sum([1 for i in s if i == 'e' or i == 'E'])
s = "helloEeeeeE"
print(eCount(s))
```

For details about list comprehension you can check this [Python - emulate sum() using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632124/python-emulate-sum-using-list-comprehension).

Comment: Why would you answer someone's assignment? Besides, if OP is struggling with `for e in s` then she's not going to get away with submitting your code anyway

Comment: Why would you suggest index-based looping here? Ugh.

Comment: @ Stefan Pochmann sorry my bad , I updated the answer. I guess habit of c++. Thanks.

Comment: Or atleast give a code in one line or in list comprehension type. So that code cannot be copy pasted

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop:

```
def eCount(s):
    count = 0
    for c in s:
        if c in ('e', 'E'):
            count += 1
    return count
```