# List Comprehensions then summing with for-loop

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and have been told to create a list using list comprehension to only display even numbers between 0-100 then add all of those numbers together.  I understand how to do it if it was just a regular list such as:

```
Total = 0
for x in range (0,101,2):
     Total += x
```

I have no idea what to do though with the comprehension.  It makes no sense to me.  This is what I have.

```
Total = 0 
x = [x for x in range (1001) if x % 2 ==0]


Total +=int(???)
print('The total is:', Total)
```

I don't know what to put in for the ??? or even if I'm going about this the right way.  Any help would be great!

Edit: I forgot to mention it needs to be in a for loop.  I don't know how to create the for loop and the comprehension list.

Comment: wrap it into `sum()` (which sums all values of a collection)

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. Replace the `range` in the first example with the comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with list comprehensions:

```
print(sum([x for x in range(0,101,2)]))
```

But you can just do:

```
print(sum(range(0,101,2)))
```

The output in both cases is 2550.

---

So apparently your requirements are to use a list comprehension *and* a for loop? I'm a bit confused but are you asking for this?

```
even_terms = [x for x in range(0,101,2)]

total = 0
for x in even_terms:
    print(x)
    total += x

print('total:', total)
```

**Output**

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
26
28
30
32
34
36
38
40
42
44
46
48
50
52
54
56
58
60
62
64
66
68
70
72
74
76
78
80
82
84
86
88
90
92
94
96
98
100
total: 2550
```

Comment: Yea, it has to be in a for-loop; I forgot to mention that.  That's the part that's confusing me.

Comment: `[x for x in range(0,101,2)]` is just `range(0,101,2)`, right?

Comment: @EricDuminil The latter returns a generator, and so is the lazy equivalent of the former. If you iterate them both you'll get the same output though.

Comment: Okay. I'm using Python 2 though, so I think `range` really is a list, as opposed to `xrange`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ah, then yeah.

Answer (score 2):

## sum

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632227/6419007) :

```
sum([x for x in range(101) if x%2 == 0])
#=> 2550
```

## for and comprehension

```
total = 0
for even in [i for i in range(101) if i%2 == 0]:
     total += even
total
#=> 2550
```

## Direct formula

```
n = 100
(n/2)*(n/2+1)
#=> 2550
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Total = reduce( lambda x, y: x + y, filter( lambda n: n % 2 == 0, range( 0, 101 )  )
```

or

```
Total = reduce( lambda x, y: x + y, range( 0, 101, 2 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example was correct. Both `range` and the list produced by the comprehension are iterable, so they both work in a for-loop. Just replace the range with the comprehension:

```
xs = [x for x in range (1001) if x % 2 ==0]

Total = 0
for x in xs:
     Total += x

print(Total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sum` is probably the canonical method for iterating over a list comprehension when adding.

```
def calculate_sum_over_range(start, end, interval=2):
    return sum(_ for _ in range(start, end, interval))

print(calculate_sum_over_range(0, 101))
```

Good luck on your homework assignment.