# How to sum all the answers from for loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Well I'm quite new to python and I'm struggling with this at the moment. I need to sum up all the answers(returns) from this for loop but I don't really know how to do this.

```
a = int(input('Enter a number plz '))
for i in range(1, a+1):
    def func(root):
        print('Number', i, 'in square root is', root)
    func(i*i)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't make it clear which numbers you want to sum up?

Comment: Enter a number plz 5
Number 1 in square root is 1
Number 2 in square root is 4
Number 3 in square root is 9
Number 4 in square root is 16
Number 5 in square root is 25 So I just need to add up all the last numbers from the rows.

Comment: Do you want the sum of all the returns of `func` - i.e. `1+2+4+9+16+25` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that would be nice.

Comment: There's no reason to redefine `func` on every loop iteration. It does not close over the loop index. `i` is a *free* variable whose value will be looked up when `func` is called. You can define `func` before the loop and get the same results.

Comment: (By "close", I mean no *value* of `i` is part of the function defintion. The name `i` will just be looked up in a non-local scope, the same as `print`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next code should solve a problem:

```
a = int(input('Enter a number plz '))
s = 0
for i in range(1, a+1):
    def func(root):
        print('Number', i, 'in square root is', root)
        return root
    s += func(i*i)
print("The sum is " + str(s))
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it solves the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler solution:

```
a = int(input('Enter a number plz '))
lst = []
for i in range(1, a+1):
    def func(root):
        print('Number', i, 'in square root is', root)
        lst.append(root)
    func(i*i)

print(f'The sum is {sum(lst)}')
```

You can create an empty list, then append all the values of `root` as you iterate through the for-loop. Now we have a list of all of the `root` values, so we can make use of the built-in `sum` function to achieve our final product.

Also note that it is not necessary to have your function in the for-loop:

```
a = int(input('Enter a number plz '))

def func(root):
        print('Number', i, 'in square root is', root)
        lst.append(root)
        
lst = []
for i in range(1, a+1):
    func(i*i)

print(f'The sum is {sum(lst)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be expressed using a list comprehension and the `sum` function:

```
a = int(input('Enter a number plz '))
print(sum(x*x for x in range(a+1)))
```

Expanded out, this would be equivalent to:

```
a = int(input('Enter a number plz '))
total = []
for x in range(a+1):
    total.append(x*x)
print(sum(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
from math import sqrt
a = int(input('Enter a number plz '))
lst = []
for i in range(1, a+1):
    print('Number', i, 'in square root is '+str(i**2))
    lst.append(i**2)
print("the list for this is "+''.join(lst))
print("the sum of all the squares is "+sum(lst))
```