# Why is the sum function in python not working?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sum

This is my code. I want add the total of the list cost, so the code will return £140, but it is not working. I want the £ sign to be in front of the sum of the cost so the user will know what the program is displaying.

```
cost = [['Lounge', 70], ['Kitchen', 70]]
print(cost)
print("£", sum(cost))
```

It returns this error message:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`

I have looked online, but none of these results have helped me:

[sum a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

[How do I add together integers in a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909052/how-do-i-add-together-integers-in-a-list-in-python)

http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsCalculatingtheSumofaListofNumbers.html

[Sum the second value of each tuple in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218112/sum-the-second-value-of-each-tuple-in-a-list)

Comment: "but none of these results have helped me" After reading the last result, what code did you try using? What happened when you tried it, and how was that different from what you wanted?

Comment: It's only failing because you aren't providing an appropriate "base" value of `[]` in place of the default `0`. (Look at `sum(cost, [])`.) But you aren't trying to sum the correct iterable in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
print("£", sum(c[1] for c in cost))
```

It's basically a condensed version of this:

```
numbers = []
for c in cost:
    numbers.append(c[1])

print("£", sum(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) But can you explain it through so that I understand how it works?

Comment: It is a shortcut for `lis = [] for c in cost:    lis.append(c[1]) print("£", sum(lis))`.  [Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is more information about generators.

Answer (score 1):

Each element in `cost` is a two-element tuple. You'd have to extract the numeric one, e.g., by using a list comprehension:

```
print("£" + str(sum(i[1] for i in cost)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter

print("£", sum(map(itemgetter(1), cost)))
```