# How to sum the selected elements from an array in python? (Multiple Inputs)

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

Here's the code:

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
x = raw_input() 

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):

print total price
```

For example the user inputs "1 3 2 2"
So the x is the multiple inputs I get from the user.
How do I sum them up? With the answer should be 1100 + 1300 + 1200 + 1200 = 4800
I want to create a code that even if I change the inputs I will still be able to sum them up. Like if I change x to 2 2 2 1 it would sum for me to 4700.

Comment: Start with, can you make it add up all the PRICES? Then can you make it add up one price that the user enters?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Add up all the PRICES? How will I be able to add up the price the user ender if I first add up all the PRICES??

Comment: if you can't solve a problem, try making an easier version and solving that. You wanted to choose some of the things and add them up, and you couldn't do it so you asked here. It's easier to write something which adds them all up, then you have got closer, got part of a solution. It's easier to ask the user for one thing. Then you have got closer, got part of the solution. I wasn't trying to give you an finished answer, I was prompting you how to get past being stuck, to get yourself closer to _creating_ an answer by trying things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn the user input into indexes like this:

```
print sum(PRICE[int(a)] for a in x.split())
```

But it will only work if the `raw_input` has the format you said: integers split by whitespace and of course it's prone to `IndexError: list index out of range` if values greater than the list length are provided.

EDIT: removed intermediary list creation as martineau suggested in the comments

Comment: `sum(PRICE[int(a)] for a in x.split())` would avoid generating an intermediate list.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on your `sum` function. Also you can use a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) rather than a list comprehension to save memory. Other than that, +1.

Comment: @Ffisegydd Thanks. Fixed the closing braket

Comment: PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
x = raw_input()
for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    print sum(PRICE[int(a)] for a in x.split())
So I did this and I get like Output:
4800
4800
4800
4800
4800
4800
But I only need 1 output and so many came out so I was wondering what went wrong?

Comment: You do not need to iterate over `PRICE` with enumerate. Just `print sum(PRICE[int(a)]...`.

Comment: @Ffisegydd Oh! I got it Thanks! ^^

Comment: @HerrActress Thank you so much for the answer! It really did a big help to me! XD

Comment: But just asking, if I want to do it in for loop format is there any possible way??

Comment: @avoid_frustration I'm glad I could help. You can wrap everything but the `PRICE` list in a `while True:` loop or `for i in range(n):` loop . But that is a different question and you can easily find an answer by browsing this site :) You can also consider accepting my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @HerrActress Thank you for your answer. This website really helps a lot when I got stuck in python.

Answer (score 1):

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
x = raw_input() 

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):

print total price
```

Hmm, I'm stuck, I can't *answer* it, but can I do anything at all?

maybe I can just print some stuff to give me more ideas.

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
x = raw_input() 
print x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    print i, v

>>>
you said 2
0 1000
1 1100
2 1200
3 1300
4 1400
5 1500
```

So `i` counts from 0 to 5, `v` is the prices, and they said `2`. Now what?

Maybe I can just add them all up for now? `v` is the price, so I'll just add them all up...

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    v = v + v

print v

>>> 
you said 3
3000
```

3000? What's 3000? Oh, it's coming from the last one, 1500 + 1500. So I can't use v like that.

Well I know about lists, what about if I do this...

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
TOTAL = []

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    TOTAL = TOTAL + v

print TOTAL

>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

No, that's an error. Uhhh...

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
TOTAL = []

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    TOTAL = TOTAL + [v]

print TOTAL

>>>
you said 2
[1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
```

That's not added anything up, that's just copied it! What a waste of time!

Hmm. Now what. I dunno, maybe I'll just print everything I have and see what's happening:

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
TOTAL = []

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    TOTAL = TOTAL + [v]
    print "x:", x, "i:", i, "v:", v, "TOTAL: ", TOTAL


print TOTAL

>>> 
you said 2
x: 2 i: 0 v: 1000 TOTAL:  [1000]
x: 2 i: 1 v: 1100 TOTAL:  [1000, 1100]
x: 2 i: 2 v: 1200 TOTAL:  [1000, 1100, 1200]
x: 2 i: 3 v: 1300 TOTAL:  [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300]
x: 2 i: 4 v: 1400 TOTAL:  [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400]
x: 2 i: 5 v: 1500 TOTAL:  [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
[1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
```

Look at that, at some point x is 2 and i is 2. That's what they typed in matching what I'm looking at. I want that.

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
TOTAL = []

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    if x == i:
        TOTAL = TOTAL + [v]

print TOTAL

>>> 
you said 2
[]
```

What? I just saw them equal and it didn't work. That's ridiculous I hate it.

```
>>> i = 1
>>> print i
1
>>> x = raw_input()
>>> print x
2
>>> raw_input() == 2
False

>>> help(raw_input)
Help on built-in function raw_input in module __builtin__:

raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline...
```

Oh that reminds me, I've heard of strings.

```
>>> x = raw_input()
>>> help(x)
no Python documentation found for '2'
>>> help(i)
Help on int object:
...
```

... hmm *Googles raw_input, int object, python, compare, reads*

```
>>> raw_input() == str(i)
True
```

Yes!

Now where was I?

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
TOTAL = []

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    if x == str(i):
        TOTAL = TOTAL + [v]

print TOTAL

>>>
you said 2
[1200]
```

This is the coolest thing ever.

*Googles 'python add list', finds [sum a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4362586) sees `sum()`

```
>>> sum(PRICE)
7500
>>> sum(TOTAL)
1200
```

Oh but I don't want to use sum, I want to add them up in the loop.

But at least now I've got something the user selected.

What else can I do? I'm stuck.

*thinks

I found `str()` a moment ago. What about

```
>>> help(str)
[gibberish]
```

I don't know what any of this stuff means :(

Hey waitaminute

```
>>> help(str)
Help on class str in module __builtin__:

class str(basestring)
 |  str(object='') -> string
 |
 |  Return a nice string representation of the object.
 |  If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
 |
 |  __eq__(...)
 |      x.__eq__(y) <==> x==y
 |
```

I just used == and now this is full of ==.

```
|  count(...)
|      S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int
|
|      Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
|      string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are interpreted
|      as in slice notation.
```

Hey what's count() doing inside str? I want to count things! Return the number of non-overlapping *yawn* *skip*.

```
|  find(...)
|      S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
|
|      Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
|      such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
|      arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
|
```

find, that's a word I recognise, and I just saw `int` earlier. Why? Oh right, help(i) said something about int.

str find something something an int? Return the lowest index in S where substring is found.

and .. and I had to str(i) before I could compare it with x

what if I

```
>>> x = raw_input()
>>> print x
2
>>> x.find
<built-in method find of str object at 0x0000000001E680A8>
```

googles built-in method

Glances at the results

Sees "If x is not a Python int object, it has to define an **index**() method"

Doesn't read it, just notices the ()

```
>>> x.find()
{error}
>>> x.find(2)
{error}
>>> x.find(str(2))
0
```

I hate this it sucks.

etc.

Hours later.

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
TOTAL = []

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    if x.find(str(i)) > -1:
        TOTAL = TOTAL + [v]

print TOTAL

>>>
you said 23
[1200, 1300]
```

OH MY WORD I FOUND THE THINGS THE USER ENTERED MORE THAN ONE OF THEM!

*hours later

```
PRICE = [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500]
TOTAL = []

x = raw_input() 
print "you said", x

for i, v in enumerate(PRICE):
    if x.find(str(i)) > -1:
        TOTAL = TOTAL + [v]

print TOTAL

add_total = 0
for i, v in enumerate(TOTAL):
    add_total = int(add_total) + int(v)

print "Total is:", str(add_total)

>>> 
you said 14
[1100, 1400]
Total is: 2500
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

This is what really happens behind all the "try this: {neat solution} :)" that goes on.

The people who know the answer, know it because they've gone through a lot of this kind of stuff. (*or maybe that's just me? D:*). And doing that a lot leads to a lot of familiarity and half remembered things you saw somewhere else, and "that won't work, I've tried it before, and here's why..." moments.

Don't avoid_frustration, go right for it. Learn to love it.

Comment: And then someone like me will smugly come along and comment "you don't need ALL THAT CODE, *smug*, why don't you *just* `total = 0` and then `for char in x: if char: total += PRICE[int(char)]` ? *beam*