# Sum of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I thought [sum a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python) would answer my question but it didn't.

For context, I am working on Project Euler, Problem 9: https://projecteuler.net/problem=9

I am getting the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

for the line

```
while sum(triplesList) <= 1000:
```

I don't know why `sum(listname)` isn't working.

Here is all the code:

```
triplesList = []

a = 0
b = 0

while sum(triplesList) <= 1000:
    a += 1 
    b += 1 

    triplesList = [[a,b] for i in range(1)]
    triplesList.append( a**2 + b **2)

    if (math.sqrt(triplesList[1])).is_integer():
        triplesList[1] = int(math.sqrt(triplesList[1]))

    if sum(triplesList[0], triplesList[1]) == 1000:
        print triplesList
        print sum(triplesList[0] , triplesList[1])
        print reduce(lambda x, y:  x * y, triplesList[0], triplesList[1])
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: `triplesList = [[a,b] for i in range(1)]` makes a `list` of `list`, therefore you cannot sum `triplesList`.

Comment: I'm confused as to why I can use the sum as a conditional BEFORE I've made it a list of lists.

Comment: Because you intialized it to `triplesList = []` so it was just a list. It doesn't become a list of lists until you perform the list comprehension that I commented on.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant that I'm confused as to why I CAN'T use the sum as a conditional...for exactly the reason you stated.  The error message comes at the while statement.

Comment: Because what would that even mean? For example what is the sum of `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`?

Comment: Pretty sure we're not understanding each other.  The error message happens when the list is still empty. It happens BEFORE triplesList becomes a list of lists.

Comment: No it doesn't. I can literally promise that `sum([])` is legal and results in `0`. The `while` condition does fail, but not until the second iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
triplesList = [[a,b] for i in range(1)]
```

To

```
triplesList = [a, b, a**2 + b**2]
```

And remove the

```
triplesList.append( a**2 + b **2)
```

This will produce a 1D list of the form [a,b,c] which is what I get the feeling you are after from your question.

The former will produce a list of the form

```
[[a,b], c]
```

Which you cannot `sum`

Answer (score 1):

**sum() only accepts a iterable objects of numbers, not a list of lists.**

triplesList is a list of lists when you do this to it:

```
triplesList = [[a,b] for i in range(1)]
```

Thus, sum() whines that it doesn't know how to add lists of lists, just lists of integers

I believe that line could instead read:

```
triplesList = [a, b]
```

Comment: [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) can be used on anything iterable which contains number types valid for the '+' operator