# Code optimization - amount of combinations

Tags: python, optimization, python-itertools

There is a number C given (C is an integer) and there is given a list of numbers (let's call it N, all the numbers in list N are integers).
My task is to find the amount of possibilities to represent C.

For example:

input:

```
C = 4

N = [1, 2]
```

output:

```
3
```

Because:

```
4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 1 + 1 + 2 = 2 + 2
```

My code is working pretty well for small numbers. However I have no idea how can I optimize it so it will work for bigger integers too. Any help will be appreciated!

There is my code:

```
import numpy
import itertools
def amount(C):
    N = numpy.array(input().strip().split(" "),int)
    N = list(N)
    N = sorted(N)
    while C < max(N):
        N.remove(max(N))
    res = []
    for i in range(1, C):
        for j in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(N, i)):
            res.append(sum(list(j)))
    m = 0
    for z in range (0, len(res)):
        if res[z] == C:
            m += 1
    if N[0] == 1:
        return m + 1 
    else:
        return m
```

Comment: There's really no need for numpy here. If anything, it's going to slow you down. And you immediately turn it into a `list` anyway. That makes no sense.

Comment: You seem to want to count partitions: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory).

Comment: You can benchmark your code against npartitions in http://docs.sympy.org/dev/_modules/sympy/ntheory/partitions_.html.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's right! I will change it in a moment. Thanks.

Comment: @BillBell Thank you. I think that might help. However I don't know how can I add my list of integers which sums are to represent C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complexity of your algorithm is `O(len(a)^С)`. To solve this task more efficiently, use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) ideas.

Assume `dp[i][j]` equals to number of partitions of `i` using terms `a[0], a[1], ..., a[j]`. Array `a` shouldn't contain duplicates. This solution runs in `O(C * len(a)^2)` time.

```
def amount(c):
    a = list(set(map(int, input().split())))

    dp = [[0 for _ in range(len(a))] for __ in range(c + 1)]
    dp[0][0] = 1

    for i in range(c):
        for j in range(len(a)):
            for k in range(j, len(a)):
                if i + a[k] <= c:
                    dp[i + a[k]][k] += dp[i][j]

    return sum(dp[c])
```

Comment: That runs very fast! Thanks for the help.

Comment: And  that's right - my array contained a  lot of duplicates.
Can you explain how does the last "if" work, please?

Comment: @Hendrra this is a kind of bounds checking. This `if` statement doesn't affect on solution at all.

Comment: ok, thanks! Can I ask for  the explanation of the first line containing dp? I think that I miss the point what it really is.

Comment: @Hendrra On the 4th line there's 2D-list generation. You can read about this trick [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a really nice trick I must say. One more question - what is dp[c]? How can we jump from a 2D list to 1D list?

Comment: @Hendrra I think you mean the `return sum(dp[c])` statement. The `sum` function returns sum of values in given container. In our case, the container is the last layer of array `dp[c]`. This is the answer on our task. You can read about `sum` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

please check this first : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics 
also this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory 
if i were you , i would divide the c on the n[i] first and check the c is not prim number 
from your example : 4/1 = [4] =>integer count 1 
 
4/2 = [2] => integer counter became 2 then do partitioning the [2] to 1+1 if and only if 1 is in the set 
what if you have 3 in the set [1,2,3] , 4/3 just subtract 4-3=1 if 1 is in the set , the counter increase and for bigger results i will do some partitioning based on the set

Comment: Thanks for all the links and a new idea.
It's a nice solution (and it shows a lot of Maths)! I will consider it too. I think however that it might be a bit slower that one above.