# Sum of list in list

Tags: python

```
mynumbers=[0,1,0,1,6,0,2,0,9]
def sum(mynumbers):
    total = 0
    for x in mynumbers:
        total =1+x
    return total
print(sum(mynumbers))
```

I do like that but I  want to find the sum in list type

how I find sum of number in list ?

Comment: please explain better what you are trying to do. to sum the list simply do: sum(number)

Comment: I find 19 but I want to find [19]

Comment: you want your answer to be a list? [sum(number)]

Comment: yeah ı know do it like this but I need different solutions

Comment: this link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python

Comment: Python has a built-in function named `sum` that computes the sum of a list very efficiently. Why do you want to write your own list summing function?

Comment: @BayramTora Python has a built-in function called sum, you don't need to define it yourself. If you want the answer to be in a list, and you want to use the sum function, you can either write `[sum(mynumbers)]` or `list(sum(mynumbers))`. Or, you can use the sum function you have defined and return the total inside a list like `return [total]`, but in my opinion you should rename your function as well then.

Comment: If you have a different question, e.g. about cumulative sum, post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are wanting here, but given your current function, do this:

```
>>> myNumbers = [0,1,0,1,6,0,2,0,9]
>>> sum(myNumbers)
19
```

The built-in `sum()` method works on an iterable already.