# How to add sums of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
num_list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

sum of num_list_1 = 10

```
num_list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
```

sum of num_list_2 = 26

how would I be able to sum together `num_list_1` and `num_list_2`.

I've tried doing it myself however as it is a list it wont let me concatenate them.

Comment: `sum(num_list_1 + num_list_2 )` should work ( the + is the concatenation but for list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

Comment: This is not clear. **What should the result be**? Do we want to concatenate the lists, like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`? Do we want the the sum of that list (`36`)? If we want `36`, are we concatenating the sublists first and then summing, or summing each and then adding the two subtotals, or does it matter? Or do we want to add values *element-wise*, like `[6,8,10,12]`? Or something else completely?

Answer (score 7):

Get the sum of each list individually, and then sum the both scalar values to get the total_sum:

```
In [1733]: num_list_1 = [1,2,3,4]

In [1734]: num_list_2 = [5,6,7,8]

In [1737]: sum(num_list_1) + sum(num_list_2)
Out[1737]: 36
```

Comment: probably the best way, as concatenating the lists waste time.

Answer (score 2):

You could sum the concatenation of the two lists:

```
sum(num_list_1+num_list_2)
```

This is what I get using the python console:

```
>>>num_list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>>num_list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
>>>sum(num_list_1+num_list_2)
>>>36
```

Or you could just sum the sums:

```
sum(num_list_1) + sum(num_list_2)
```

which leads to the same output but in a probably faster way:

```
>>>num_list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>>num_list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
>>>sum(num_list_1) + sum(num_list_2)
>>>36
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have several lists (more than 2) you could `sum` the sums by applying `map` to the results:

```
sum(map(sum,(num_list_1,num_list_2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` acts as **concatenating** in case of lists, so 
`sum(num_list_1 + num_list_2)` will help

Answer (score 1):

## First Define both lists

```
num_list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
num_list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
```

## then use Sum() For Both list

```
print(sum(num_list_1) + sum (num_list_2))
```

## Also You Can Do This :

```
print(sum(num_list_1+ num_list_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
>>> num_list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> num_list_2 = [5,6,7,8]
>>> sum(num_list_1+num_list_2)
>>> 36
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` takes an iterable, so you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to chain your lists and feed the resulting iterable to `sum`:

```
from itertools import chain

num_list_1 = [1,2,3,4]
num_list_2 = [5,6,7,8]

res = sum(chain(num_list_1, num_list_2))  # 36
```