# I have a numpy array which contains a number of arrays within. How can I sum all of the arrays within resulting in a single numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

So I'm a little lost here. I have a numpy array that contains multiple array within it. My goal is to sum all of the arrays INSIDE of the big array, resulting in a singular array containing those summed values.

I've already tried using np.sum() but this goes one step too far and sums everything returning a single integer value.

an example of what I am trying to accomplish:
    a = (array([1, 2, 3]), array([3, 4, 5]))
**perform some steps and the desired result is:
    a = (array([4, 6, 8]))

Comment: "I have a numpy array that contains multiple array within it." What? So your array's `dtype` is object? Please provide a [mcve] Note, `a = (array([1, 2, 3]), array([3, 4, 5]))` is not an array that contains a number of arrays. It is a tuple with array objects inside of it.

Comment: let's be clear - is this a multidimensional array of numbers, or an object dtype array containing arrays? The difference is important, but your description is vague.  Did you read about the `axis` parameter for `sum`?

Comment: Are all the arrays inside of the same length?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use the summation operation for this purpose. You don't need any specific built-in function to do this task.

```
import numpy as np

a = (np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([3,4,5])))
sum = a[0] + a[1]
print('The summation of two sub-arrays: ',sum)
```

After the above code is interpreted, you will get a result like this;

> The summation of two sub-arrays:  [4 6 8]

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE: Better solution w/ vectorized addition

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

a = (np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([3,4,5]))
print(sum(a))
>>> [4 6 8]
```

#### Original, clumsy, non numpyic solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
a = (np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([3,4,5]))  
b = zip(*a) 
c = [sum(arr) for arr in b]
print(c)
>>> [4, 6, 8]
d = np.array(c)
print(d)
>>> [4 6 8]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add up the arrays? Why the transpose using `zip` then a list-comprehension wiht `sum`? Just `a[0] + a[1]` or even `sum(a)` would work

Comment: Does that work for any number of np.arrays? Makes sense! +1 vectorized operations :-)

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! Yeah I ended up using the sum function because I had many sub-arrays worked great. Thank you all for the feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to iterate through np lists elements so check this for iterating  [pairwise](http:////https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389507/iterating-over-every-two-elements-in-a-list) and secondly check this [sum list's elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)