# Trying to map through return list of dictionary with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, return

I want to do something pretty simple, but I don not know why it is not working

```
N = int(input())
numbers = list(input())
print(numbers)
def switch(x):
    return {
      '1': 2,
      '2': 5,
      '3': 5,
      '4': 4,
      '5': 5,
      '6': 6,
      '7': 3,
      '8': 7,
      '9': 6,
    }[x]

print(list(map(switch, numbers)))
```

I have the above code and what I want is to based in a number sum all of the results for each of its digits from a function called switch

Comment: `numbers = list(input())` this will always be a list of one, i am guessing you want to put in multiple numbers like `1 2 3 6 5` if so then you need to split the string like `numbers = list(input("num: ").split())`

Comment: No @ChrisDoyle, the numbers are as such 115380, for instance I want to get [1,1,5,3,8,0]

Comment: "I don not know why it is not working" We can only help diagnose the problem if you explain it. What happened when you tried the code? How is that different from what you want to happen?

Comment: What should the result from `switch` be when the digit is `'0'`? It seems like you just have an oversight there, and then the *actual question* is "how do I sum a list of numbers in python?" which you  answer by putting that exact thing [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+do+I+sum+a+list+of+numbers+in+python%3F).

Comment: Either way, the question should be closed - as a typo, or as a duplicate of [Sum a list of numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python).

Comment: There is no such case of 0, @KarlKnechtel

Comment: No, it should not, @KarlKnechtel

Comment: " the numbers are as such 115380, for instance I want to get [1,1,5,3,8,0]" Clearly it is possible to have a `0` as one of the digits that you feed to the `switch`.

Comment: "I am getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 18, in <module> print(sum(map(switch, numbers))) File "main.py", line 5, in switch return { KeyError: '0'" **That is because there is, in fact "such case"**. It is telling you exactly what the problem is (and which you should have said in the question originally).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I just figured out what I should do... I need to filter out the zeros from my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of numbers as input from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663306/get-a-list-of-numbers-as-input-from-the-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to sum all digits?
in that case you can use `sum` function:

```
...
print(sum(map(switch, numbers)))
```

You don't need to convert `map` result to `list` since `sum` accepts iterables.

Comment: Hello, Hook, I am just having a problem when trying to get a list from the dictionary function in this line of code

Comment: Why? it worked for me (i've tested it). can you copy your traceback?
Also, make sure you don't need '0' because you started from '1'.

Comment: Works for me as well.  However, since sum takes an iterator, there is no need for the list call, right?

Comment: @Malcolm Correct.

Comment: I am getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(sum(map(switch, numbers)))
  File "main.py", line 5, in switch
    return {
KeyError: '0'


Comment: That is because you should add `'0': 0` to dictionary in `switch` function.