# How to add each element of a list to each other

Tags: python, list

In this given list :
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..]` .
I'm trying to add 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5.
Please help, I'm new to Python.

Comment: ```sum(list)```

Comment: You can use the sum() function, like `sum(list)` to find the total

Comment: if you want to add list elements, you can use directly sum(given_list)

Comment: THANKS I NEED IT FOR CREATING BLACKJACK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
 output = sum([1,2,3,4,5])

 print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5]

```
Sum = sum(numbers)
print(Sum)
```

Output will be: 25

In case you want to achieve your total Sum of elements + a number you do below. It means total Sum of elements of Numbers + 10

```
Sum10 = sum(numbers,10)
print(Sum10)
```

Output will be: 35

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
listsum =0
for i in list :
    listsum+=i
print ("Sum of list elements is:", sum)
```

OR

print(sum(list))

Note: here list is the name of the variable that is holding your list.

Comment: Bad use of variables, ```sum``` is inbuilt function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum` function

```
l1=[1,2,2,4,5,6,7]
print(f"Sum of {'+'.join([str(x) for x in l1])} is: {sum(l1)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:
1 Manual:

```py
sum=0
list1= [1,2,3,4,5]
for v in list1:
    sum+=v
print(sum)
```

2. Python way:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(sum(list1)) # this will directly print out sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'sum()' function:

```
num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

sum_of_list = sum(num_list)

print(sum_of_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum1 = 0

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

for x in range(0, len(list1)):
    sum1 = sum1 + list1[x]

print(sum1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add list items together use this code :

`sum([1,2,3,4,5])`

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
 sum([1,2,3,4,5,...])
```

And as you are a beginner, doing following for loop will help you understand for loops as well

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,...]
my_sum = 0
for each_num in my_list:
    my_sum = each_num + my_sum  # This could also be written as my_sum += each_num
print(my_sum)
```

Solving problems in a multiple ways will help you reinforce your learning