# Python - sum all elemeents in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Good evening good people.
i am asking for assistance if possible.
i am trying to create a simple shopping list that sums the total in the end.
however for some reson i cannont understand how i can sum all elements in my list. there are no limits on how many items one can add, so the sum should add all values in range etc.

1. how can i make it so my code prints out the summarized value of all numbers under "sum"

my code is as follows

```
    import math
import pandas as pd
myTup = ()
myList = []


def Innlesning():#FUNKSJON FOR INNLESING AV BRUKERNDATA
 global myList #DEFINERER LISTE SOM GLOBAL VARIABEL FOR UTHENTING I ANNEN FUNKSJON
 global summer


 while True:
   
  itemName = input("Navn på produkt ")
  if itemName.isalpha():
   break
  else:
   print("Benytt kun bokstaver")
  pass
 while True:
  itemNum = input("Antall ")
 
  if itemNum.isdigit():
   break
  else:
   print("Benytt kun tall")
 pass
 
 itemPrice = input("pris på produkt ")
 
 while True:
  if itemPrice.isdigit():
   break
  else:
   print("Benytt kun tall")
 pass
 myTup = (itemName,itemNum,itemPrice,int(itemNum)*int(itemPrice) )
 myList.append(myTup)
 myList.sort()
 lis=list(myList)



    
    

def utskrift(): #FUNKSJON FOR UTSKRIFT, MED PANDA TABLE)
    global myList
    #print(myList)
    print(myList)
    from tabulate import tabulate
    y=len(myList)
    headers=["NAVN","ANTALL","PRIS","SUM"]
    print(tabulate(myList, headers, tablefmt="grid"))#PRODUSERER TABLE UTSKRIFT
    #print("totalsum for dine varer er = " + """Summer kolonne""" + " .-Nkr") 
    
    ###hvordan kan jeg summere 
    #totalsum   = sum(list(myList[0]))
    #print("Totalsum er:" + totalsum)
    return myList
    pass





while True:

 Innlesning()
 i = input("Trykk Enter for nytt produkt - ELLER skriv inn 0 FOR UTSKRIFT: ")
 if  i =="0":
        break
 print("Your input:", i)
utskrift()
print("AVSLUTTER")


#HENTER UT FUNKSJONENE FOR INNDATA, DERETTER UTSKRIFT"
```

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOqxx.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum a list of numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362586/sum-a-list-of-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
myTup = (itemName,itemNum,itemPrice,int(itemNum)*int(itemPrice) )
myList.append(myTup)
...
```

i will assume that the number you wanted to add together is `int(itemNum)*int(itemPrice)`, which is every last element of the tuple (`myTup[-1]`)

what you can do is:

```
...
total = 0
for tuple in myList:
    total += tuple[-1]
...
```

when the loop is done, the `total` should be the number you want